What is the best way to setup SQL Server audit to get all SELECT for schema?
My goal:

Show all tables from specific schema which are used in SELECT queries for all users in SQL Server database.
[Optional] Show all tables from specific schema which are used in queries for all users (around 300 sql and AD users) except one user in SQL Server database.

I have added specification:

But still see deletes/inserts/updates:

Questions:

Is audit log best option to achieve my goal ?
What specification should I use ?


See if filtering the audit is of any help.

SQL server has an inbuilt feature called SQL Server Audit, which allows detailed audit of database activities. You can set this up using SQL Server management or running a T-SQL script. This documentation will give you a step-by-step process of enabling auditing for all SELECTs on a specific schema using the earlier stated tools.
The reason I am linking to the documentation and not summarizing the steps here is that there is so much information on there, that it will be best for you to go through it on the docs.
I hope this helps.

Run the following 2 scripts and view Audit Logs. You will see just select statements.
1. First Script
USE [master]
GO


CREATE SERVER AUDIT [Database_Select_Audit]
TO FILE 
(   FILEPATH = N'E:\SQL Files\'
    ,MAXSIZE = 0 MB
    ,MAX_ROLLOVER_FILES = 2147483647
    ,RESERVE_DISK_SPACE = OFF
) WITH (QUEUE_DELAY = 0, ON_FAILURE = CONTINUE

--, AUDIT_GUID = '5495e1cb-a031-4c2f-a320-aff163c8aa3f'

)
ALTER SERVER AUDIT [Database_Select_Audit] WITH (STATE = ON)
GO

2. Second Script
USE [TARGET_DATABASE_NAME]
GO

CREATE DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION [Audit_Data_Select_From_Database]
FOR SERVER AUDIT [Database_Select_Audit]
ADD (SELECT ON DATABASE::[TARGET_DATABASE_NAME] BY [public])

WITH (STATE = ON)
GO



I have add similar audit but still it is storing deletes :(. Finally I go with audit custom with filters.
